# Warehouse modeling in Anylogic:

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to model unloading a truck into a warehouse by following the Job Shop tutorial in the documentation here: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp

How do I prevent 2 fork lifts from trying to fill the same column in a pallet rack at once? Right now they will just drive into the same column, and then queue up. I would prefer the fork lift to pick a different column in any (or the same) pallet rack.

Answer (score 1):

the default behavior in AnyLogic is to store the pallets automatically in the racks, the way you can avoid these problems is to define the position yourself... 
See the following image: 
[image]

Now you can set up your own logic to define where you want to place your pallet in order to avoid doing it in the same column... and for that you have many functions that you can review at https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp looking for pallet rack or racksystem depending on what you have.
Functions like reserve() isFree() etc will help you define your logic to specify explicitly the cell that you will use.